# download files from Compute Engine to my local machine

Tags: ubuntu

I have some files that i created in a server in Compute Engine connected by Shh. Now I would like to retrieve these files into my local host.
How could I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use scp command

https://linuxhandbook.com/scp-command/

Or

Google Cloud Shell GUI has upload/download capability.

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files